# Facebook Graph API - Reply to reply in a Page Post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to use Facebook Graph API to reply to comments left by users in a Facebook Page which I am the admin.

For top-level comments, everything is fine: I send a request to `POST /{comment_id}/comments?message=message` and it returns an OK with the reply comment_id.

But when I try to send a request to reply a comment that's already a reply to a top-level comment, API just returns OK with the new comment_id, but in the wrong hierachical level.

Example:

I created a Page Post in some Test Page, and left a comment (`1 in image = 113788881016328_113789711016245`) to this Post with some other user just using Facebook's interface.

Then I made a request to `POST 113788881016328_113789711016245/comments?message=Reply to Comment 1` and replied it with another comment from the test user using the page interface (`3 in image = 113788881016328_113791161016100`: so, it is a reply to a Page's reply to another comment).

Finally, I made another request to reply this reply `POST 113788881016328_113791161016100/comments?message=Reply to reply` and it was created fine, but not in the right level. But, if I reply to this same id as the Page by the Facebook interface like a normal user, it creates in the desired level:

[image: Example]

2 and 4 = API requests. 1, 3 and 5 = interaction directly in Page

When I do a request to `GET 113788881016328_113789711016245/comments`, it shows me all the other 4 comments in the image as children of comment 1.

So, the question is: am I doing something wrong or Facebook Graph API just only allows replies to a top-level comment like Instagram API? There's any way I can make a request behave like in the comment "5" from image?

Comment: Have you got any solution for this?

Comment: @VineethKuttipurathkottayodan there's a ticket open in Facebook's Bug Support, still no official solution: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/688077532586560/ please, check "Same here!" button there to help